# How to upload image file in django related to a perticular user only

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file in Django such that uploaded file is linked to a foreign key. i.e. if I upload a file then in the database it should reflect that with which database subject it is related to

This is my views.py file:

```
def pod_upload (request, pk):
    lr_object = get_object_or_404(LR, id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadPODform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.lr_connected = lr_object
        form.save()

        if form.is_valid():
            form.lr_connected = lr_object
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadPODform()
        form.lr_connected = lr_object


    return render(request, 
'classroom/suppliers/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
class UploadPODform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Uploaded_pod
        fields = ('document',)

        def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UploadPODform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # 
self.fields['lr_connected'].required = False
```

This is my models.py file:

```
class Uploaded_pod(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='pods/')
    lr_connected = models.ForeignKey(LR, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='lr_pod')
```

I expect that if some user uploads a file then it must be saved with respect to the LR object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['uploads', instance.lr_connected.pk, filename])


class Uploaded_pod(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to=image_path)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more ? What should we I put in filename ?

Comment: what should be the filename in this ? Can you please elaborate ? @ruddra

Comment: @chirag filename is a default argument for this function, you don't need to put anything for this. filename is the actual filename of the file you are uploading